# Which partner program is appropriate for simply accessing r_basicprofile using the v2 API?

Tags: linkedin-api

I have an integration that utilizes the LinkedIn v1 API to import users' basic profile information. With v1 about to be deprecated, I've looked into how to maintain this access using the v2 API. Apparently this requires becoming a member of one of their partner programs. However, LinkedIn's documentation does not make it clear which partner program would be the right one to apply to for this use case. Does anyone know which partner program (https://developer.linkedin.com/partner-programs) to use for this?

Unfortunately their customer service reps I've discussed this matter with have not had an answer for me and instead directed me here...

Comment: LinkedIn actively discourages integrating with the API. My advice would be to completely cut them out of your application, as the trend has been to disclose less and less information for years without any clear paths to keep access. First, access to connections was restricted, now the v1 API is being overhauled for no apparent reason other than to get people off the integration.

Comment: I certainly agree with your sentiment there. Unfortunately, I'm compelled to explore whatever paths there may be to maintain the same access in v2 as in v1. As they seemingly do provide an avenue for maintaining this access via their partner programs, I would very much appreciate any advice on which partner program would be appropriate for my use case! :) I was hoping LinkedIn themselves monitored SO posts with their tags but so far it doesn't appear that way :(